Is there a property in Hibernate to create the SQL shorter aliases for tables and columns?
Is there a property in Hibernate to create the SQL shorter aliases for tables and columns?
I use JPA 2.1 + Hibernate 5.2.18.
The names of the aliases created by Hibernate are like these:
SELECT conhecocor0_.codConhecimentoOcorrencia AS codConhe1_72_0_,conhecocor0_.codTipoOcorrencia AS codTipoO2_72_0_,...FROM ConhecimentoOcorrencia conhecocor0_INNER JOIN Conhecimento conhecimen1_ ON conhecocor0_.numero=conhecimen1_.numero...

I would to change this default behaviour with 10 first chars of each, to just 1 char, like this:
SELECT c0_.codConhecimentoOcorrencia AS c1_72_0_,c0_.codTipoOcorrencia AS cO2_72_0_,...FROM ConhecimentoOcorrencia c0_INNER JOIN Conhecimento c1_ ON c0_.numero=c1_.numero...

because I have some big QLs that consume so much String (char[]) RAM!
And I think it would be possible to save many spaces in RAM after this change.
I tried to look for some property in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html but I didn't find a solution for this.
For example, Hibernate creates these SQLs using a variable that I found in HB source code for all entities:
Visual VM showing all SQLs created by Hibernate on deploy of the webapp
The majority use of these instances (char[], HashMap, etc) are from HB. This image was saved just after the deploy of the webapp:
Visual VM showing the classes loaded on webapp deploy
Look at this example of SQL generated on deploy by HB for just one entity:
SQL char array with references in memory

I have honestly never heard of concern over alias length.  Typically, Hibernate will just generate a raw SQL query and pass it to the database.  The size of the query in terms of number of characters is usually not a concern.  How big are your queries?

I have, for example, some queries with 120 kb de chars with the normal way HB generates the SQL. Because it creates aliases with 10 chars + sufix (sequential number) + "". If it would be possible to create the aliases with 1 char + sufix + "", the final size would be so much smaller.

Why does the size of the query string matter to you and why should that affect performance?

For example, just after the deploy, Hibernate creates many SQLs using the variable staticLoadQuery for all entities with size more that 50/60/.../until 114 kb. I am going to send the images in a new "edit" for this question.
